# TPL Task Parentage Cancel

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

Two TPL tasks, MethodA and MethodB run as AttachedToParent tasks.  MethodA should only run if the args contains some data e.g. args.Criteria.Any() -> MethodB task should always run as it processes other types found in args e.g. args.Collection etc.

I would like to prevent MethodA from running should args not have data to process but still call MethodB. The code below works but is inefficient -> any ideas on how to improve it?

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodA(args, token), token, TaskCreationOptions.AttachedToParent, TaskScheduler.Default)
    .ContinueWith
        (
         task => 
               { 
                     Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MethodB(args, token)); 
                }
        );
```

MethodA runs only if args contains some data (Not shown).
MethodB always runs.

PS - ContinuationTasks or OnComplete parallel extensions do not work as they ensure the task is completed but not the continuation code.

Comment: Ugly maybe, but why inefficient? Besides, the code doesn't do what you describe, it just runs MethodA after MethodB

Comment: I don't understand, how are you making sure that `MethodA()` doesn't run when there aren't any criteria? I don't see anything like that in your code.

Comment: Ugly - agreed :) for brevity I have not shown the full code. As described, I am looking for a way to have MethodA ONLY run on a conditional basis. MethodB should always run. An example is ~ args contains types which are mandatory so MethodB processes these whilst if some additional types exists then MethodA needs to be called. I hope this is clearer :)